# Error creating docker image: "/bin/sh: 1: -E: not found"

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I try to build image from Dockerfile, but I receive this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: -E: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | -E bash -' returned a non-zero code: 127.
```

I get it because of the following line in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN  install curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | -E bash -
```

Comment: Are you passing a build arg for `NODE_VERSION` and `ANGULAR_VERSION` when you build it? Any reason to not start with one of the official nodejs images as your base?

Answer (score 5):

> I try to build image from Dockerfile, but I receive this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: -E: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | -E bash -' returned a non-zero code: 127.
```

As you can see in Dockerfile RUN as well as in above error

```
RUN  install curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | -E bash -
```

`-E bash -` has no meaning without `sudo`

**Please correct to**

```
RUN  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -
```

Since nowhere `USER <user>` is specified in your Dockerfile, during build default user will be root as your parent image is ubuntu.

Please note the default user in a Dockerfile is the user of the parent image, in your case its `ubuntu:latest` ( `FROM ubuntu:latest AS deploy`). There can be images which are non-root by default.

If you're installing on non-docker environment you can use `curl -sL .... | sudo -E bash -`

```
$ man sudo
   .....
-E, --preserve-env
    Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing 
    environment variables. The security policy may return 
    an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```